# changing background color with text input

Tags: javascript, button, input, background-color

So I have one text input and one button. What I need to do is to make it that when you write a color name in the text input and then press the button it will appear as the background color ***of the page***. I.E. I i will write "blue" the background color will become blue. i am new to java script so be gentle with me. and thanks.

I need to make this code with only JavaScript, without any jquery.

**HTML**

```
<table bgcolor="#999999" align="center">
    <tr><td align="center"><b>Write the background color you want:</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="center"><form name="forme"><input type="text" name="colors"  /></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="center"><input type="button" value="Click for result" name="press" onclick="color('green')" id="getText" /></form></td></td>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function color(theColor) {
    document.bgColor =theColor;
}
```

Comment: then why you added jquery tag??

Comment: The attribute you are trying to use is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.bgColor

Answer (score 3):

for changing the background color of body you need:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = theColor ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the color of button,

```
 $("#btn").click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color",$("#txt1").val());
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ry3Lv/2/)

If you want to change the color of whole body,

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
  $("body").css("background-color",$("#txt1").val());
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ry3Lv/3/)

**Edit**
Using javascript,

```
function color() {

    document.body.style.background  =document.getElementsByName("colors")[0].value;
}
```

**[Updated Demo using only javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/Ry3Lv/9/)**

Comment: he wants it in javascript, please read the question completely.

Comment: oh i didnt notice that. Initially he tagged this question with jquery. Thats why..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.bgColor. `document.bgColor` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
<input type="button" id="btn1" />

<script>
    document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
    };
</script>`
```